# Is Rice's Theorem equivalent to the Halting problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, proof, computation-theory, halting-problem

As I understand it [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) seems to imply the existence of the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). That is, with Rice's Theorem, we can prove that the Halting problem is undecidable. However, to me, it seems like one could write a proof using that the Halting problem is undecidable to show Rice's Theorem. I'm not exactly sure how one would go about proving such a thing (though it seems by contradiction would be the natural thing to do), but it *feels* to me that that it should be possible?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right website for this kind of questions. Try with cs stackexchange.

Comment: https://arbital.com/p/rice_theorem/?l=5n6